# Google Analytics Error in server

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I'm using Google Analytics Core Reporting API ([Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php)).

When I run this in my local system it is working. But, when I uploaded in my dedicated server it is not working and throwing me the error as:

> Google_Service_analytics class not found.

Please help do let me know where i'm going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using composer on your dedicated server?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I reformatted your question for clarity. In addition I added the tag for the google analytics api in order to attract a wider audience.

In addition I advise you to mention more about your dedicated server environment, such as whether you have [ssh access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssh) and the structure of your directories and code.